# Occassional Oauth exceptions - user hasn't authorized the app

Tags: security, facebook-oauth

I am fairly sure my application is handling most things properly as it works 88-92% of the time, but way too often I am getting the following error:
(OAuthException - #200) (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action

I don't understand how this is possible.  When the user is requested to authorize the app, I do not see any way for them accept a subset of the permissions required (it's all or nothing).  If they proceed, and I get an auth token, doesn't that mean my app has the needed access?  If not, how are users doing that, and how can I prevent or at least detect it?

In terms of background, my application is a kiosk application that takes the user's photo and allows them to post it (or, more precisely, a link to it) on their facebook timeline.  The kiosk gets the user's authorization, then passes the token and all other data to a central web service that then communicates with Facebook.  This has been working 88-92% of the time for the past week.  Despite no code changes or application configuration changes, prior to the past week it had been working 93-96% of the time for the couple weeks prior to that, and about 98% earlier than that.

Is there any way I can provide some details (usernames and auth tokens) to facebook for more analysis?  PLEASE HELP!

Comment: What do your app insights say about which permissions the users are accepting and/or revoking? You know users can opt to skip publishing permissions right? There's a blog post [explaining how the current login dialog works] (https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/12/12/providing-people-greater-clarity-and-control/) and a document [clarifying how to handle users granting a subset of permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/handling-revoked-permissions/)

Comment: Where does insights provide information on permissions?

Comment: As for the blog, I'm not seeing any of that.  What I (my users) see is http://erickassan.net/images/FacebookAuthScreen.png  If users can edit permissions from this screen, please let me know how.

Comment: That's the old dialog, the new one is still rolling out and splits read and write into two screens- please look at the links i added above. If you want to test the new dialog, all Test Users should be seeing the new dialog. The permission sets prompted for and which subsets were accepted are in insights in the Users section, i think it's the Growth tab

Comment: Thank you for the additional info.  Given the new dialog hasn't yet been rolled out to my application, I'm still at a loss to explain the failures.  Am I still getting an auth token even when the user selects cancel?  Looking at the insights page you mentioned, I'm seeing only two permission sets - what the app requests and basic.  The latter I presume is for users who had already authorized the first permission set.  I'm also baffled by how the rate of these errors has increased so substantially (400%) in the past few weeks week.